# find: name pattern as a variable

Tags: linux, bash, find

A trivial situation where I want to manage the file name patterns for the `find` command in the variable:

```
/bin/bash
EXCLUDE="! \( -name "\"run*"\" -o -name "\"doc*"\" \)"
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f "$EXCLUDE"
```

The expectation is to find all the files not matching the `$EXCLUDE` pattern.

The approach doesn't work, despite the same pattern directly works as expected.

In the shell tracing mode I observed something that I blame as a potential rootcause - the `$EXCLUDE` variable is evaluated between single quotes:

```
set -x
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f "$EXCLUDE"
+ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f '! \( -name "run*" -o -name "doc*" \)'
find: paths must precede expression: ! \( -name "run*" -o -name "doc*" \)
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

The substituted `$EXCLUDE` variable appears in the line starting with `+` and my `find` command won't return anything with those characters: `'! \( -name "run*" -o -name "doc*" \)'`.

Is there a way to remove those quotes, which are not a part of the variable, or I am missing something bigger?

Comment: `"$EXCLUDE"` is expanded to a single word, but `find` expects separate arguments. I didn't find a way to make this work because you want the shell to split the value of `$EXCLUDE` but not expand the file name patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) -- use an array instead:

```sh
EXCLUDE=( '!' '(' -name 'run*' -o -name 'doc*' ')' )
```

Then use the array expansion syntax

```sh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f "${EXCLUDE[@]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Store the arguments in an array:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
EXCLUDE=( '!' '(' '-name' 'run*' '-o' '-name' 'doc*' ')' )
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f "${EXCLUDE[@]}"
```

This avoids quoting errors.